# Debug Java app (Tanuki service wrapper) in Eclipse

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, debugging, java-service-wrapper

How do I debug a Java application contained in a wrapper (like Tanuki Java Windows Service Wrapper) from within Eclipse? I understand that there is an option to set debug=true within the wrapper and run it., but if I want to do a live debug (stepping in/out), is there an option/method? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still attach a remote debugger from eclipse to the process using its process id.

Comment: thats an idea. i will try it.

Comment: that is pretty much *the* idea :)

Comment: quick follow up question. Where do I give the process id within eclipse? I can debug a webapp with the local port, but where do i set the process id?

Comment: You don't set the process id for Java remote debugging at all, you need the host/port to connect. See http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53459.html

Comment: @MiserableVariable BUMP I have sort of the same issue, even if I enter host:port in eclipse I get kicked out. Any ideas?